# Ruby - Prevent auto escape characters

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, ruby-1.8.7

I have e.g. `r = "\t"` and `a = "thisisabigbad\wolf"`

How can I prevent ruby from auto escaping my string and also count the `\` at the same time?

```
a.count r #=> this should return 2 instead of 0
```

I wish to do `a.count` and receive `2`

Comment: How is "auto escape" different from "escape"?

Comment: I wish to count \ but in this case. it is escaping it. I though it is part of ruby's implementation @sawa

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes:

```
[17] pry(main)> r = '\t'
=> "\\t"
[18] pry(main)> r.size
=> 2
[20] pry(main)> a = 'thisisabigbad\wolf'
=> "thisisabigbad\\wolf"
[21] pry(main)> a.size
=> 18
```